# Big-O/Big-Oh Notation Problem

Tags: big-o

I am going over the Big-Oh notation, and I have a problem understanding the solution to this question:

```
Is 2n + 10 ≡ O(n)?
Can we find c and n0?

2n + 10 <= cn
(c-2)n >= 10
n >= 10/(c-2)

Pick c = 3 and n0 = 10
```

There is also a graph used in this example:

[image: Graph]

I am confused as to how c = 3 and how n0 = 10?  Can somebody please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve `2n + 10 <= cn` differently.

```
2n + 10 <= cn
2 + 10/n <= c //divide by n
c >= 2 + 10/n
```

Clearly `c` has to be bigger than 2. Now take your favorite number bigger than 2. Uhm. `c=2.718`. This gives

```
2n + 10 <= 2.718*n
10 <= 0.718*n //subtract 2n
13.93 <= n
```

Thus, `2n + 10 <= c*n`. If we take `c=2.718` and `n` bigger than `15`. (15 because it's bigger than the limit, 13.93, and I like 15.)

Any c bigger than 2 works, c=100000000000000000000000 is fine too (but, it costs much ink and paper to write down.)

It might have been easier to take `c=3`. That would give

```
2n + 10 <= 3*n
10 <= n //subtract 2n
```

This makes 3 the most logical / natural solution.

Answer (score 2):

To say a function `f(n)` is `O(n)` means you can find `c` and `n0` such that for all `n >= n0`, `f(n) <= cn`.

To verify this in your case: if n >= 10, then:

```
f(n) =  2n + 10
     <= 3n         // because 10 <= n
     = cn
```

So `f(n) <= cn` for all `n >= 10`, so `f(n)` is an `O(n)` function.

Note that other values for `c` and `n0` work; you just need to find one pair.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however I am afraid that I am still struggling to get to terms with this particular question (or with Big-O notation in general).  Do you know of any helpful resources that I could refer to?  With regards to `Pick c = 3 and n0 = 10` - is this asking me to use these values and attempt to solve whether or not 2n + 10 ≡ O(n) or am I mistaken?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: See @Ishtar's answer, which approaches it from the other end.

Answer (score 0):

In Big-O notation you drop numbers added and multiplied.
And also use the largest power.

```
10*N^3+ 23*N^2 + 43*N + 154 = O(N^3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let f(n) = 2n+10
as per the Big-Oh notation,
f(n)<= c*g(n)  ----->eq1(let)
2n+10 <= 2n+n  
2n+10 <= 3n     for n>=10 //here the constant 10  is replaced by n ---->eq2
```

comparing eq1 with eq2
***c=3*** and ***g(n)=n*** for value of n=10

**f(n)= O(g(n)) = O(n)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).