# Big O complexities 10n = O(n²)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am trying to understand the Big O notations, but it's bit harder than I thought. I have a function 10*n* for which I want to prove that 10*n* = O(*n*²).

Can somebody tell how to prove this?

Possible values I can use are:

- c = 0, n0 = 1
- c = 1, n0 = 1
- c = 2, n0 = 5
- c = 1, n0 = 9

Comment: Possible values I can use are c = 0, n0 = 1 
c = 1, n0 = 1
c = 2, n0 = 5
c = 1, n0 = 9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big-O/Big-Oh Notation Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791146/big-o-big-oh-notation-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find values for *n*<sub>0</sub> and *c*, such that for every *n* ≥ *n*<sub>0</sub> it is true that 10*n* ≤ *c⋅n*²

Let's try the possibilities you presented in comments:

- *c*=0, *n*<sub>0</sub>=1

  No, that won't work, already for *n=1* we find that 10*n* > 0*n*²
- *c*=1, *n*<sub>0</sub>=1

  No, that won't work, as for *n=1* we find that 10*n* > 1*n*²
- *c*=2, *n*<sub>0</sub>=5

  Yes, that will work: we must prove:

  10*n* ≤ *2n²*, so

  10 ≤ 2*n*, so

  5 ≤ *n*.

  Since *n*<sub>0</sub>=5 and since we must check only for *n* ≥ *n*<sub>0</sub>, we have a statement that is always true.
- *c*=1, *n*<sub>0</sub>=9

  No, that won't work, as for *n=9* we find that 10*n* > 1*n*². NB: it would work if we chose *n*<sub>0</sub>=10, but that was not among the options you gave.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Big O notation is quite simple:

g(n) = O(f(n)) if when n is big enough, the increasing rate of g(n) is less than or equal to the increasing rate of f(n) (with equal, I mean the ratio is some number less than infinity)

So if g(n) = O(f(n)) then

[image]

k can be 0 or a positive number less than infinity.

So in your case

[image]

Imply 10n = O(n^2)